# Several sentences/text Sine wave Jquery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I already found and tweaked code that will animate a sentence, letter by letter in a sine way. However, there are a few issues:

- I can't seem to get it to work on several sentences, basically imagine two or three more sentences like the one in the example underneath it, so that all sentences are underneath each other and animated simultaneously
- Can't figure out how to make the sentence animation end and reappear at left of the page again at the start of the list options div block

[Here is the link](http://codepen.io/rtr365/pen/JdROVo?editors=100)
Here is the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>

<body>
  <div id="options">
    <ul id="list" style="">
      <li>ABOUT</li>
      </br>
      <li>THE STREAM</li>
      </br>
      <li>TELL YOUR STORY</li>
      </br>
      <li>COMING EVENTS</li>
      </br>
      <li>CONTACT</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="sentences_block">
    <div id="elements" style="margin-left:50px;"></div>
    <div>
</body>
<style type="text/css">
  .letter {
        font-family: sans-serif;
        font-size: 40px;
        font-weight: bold;
        position: absolute;
        top: -100px; 
        left: 0px;
    }
  #list {
  list-style-type: none; 
  color: #0067CE;font-weight: bold;
  font-style:arial;
  font-size:15px;
  float:right;
  }
  #options {
  margin-right:20px;
  }
</style>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
        var width = $(window).width() - 0;
        var starttime = new Date().getTime();
        var letters = document.location.hash ? document.location.hash.substr(1) : 'sentence';
        var elements = $('#elements');

        for (i = 0; i < letters.length; i++) {
            $('<div>', {
                html: letters[i]
            })
            .addClass('letter')
            .appendTo(elements);
        }

        function run() {
            var elapsed = new Date().getTime() - starttime;
            var pos = elapsed * 0.2;

            $('div.letter').each(function(index, letter) {
                var posx = (pos + 40 * index) % width;
                var posy = 200 + Math.sin(posx / 50) *25;
                $(letter).css('left', posx + 'px');
                $(letter).css('top', posy + 'px');

            });

        }

        setInterval(run, 3);
    });
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you please explain more about your two questions please? cause I think I can have the answer for you, but did not understand what you really need. your first question you mean you want to have more than one sentence and sow the second one after the first one showed and get out of the page? or you want to show the second one under the first one simultaneously? your second question, you want to modify the width of the  `sentences_block` `div` to not 100% of the page and it should end before the `options` `div`? are these two correct?

Comment: @EhsanT I want to show the second and third sentence under the first one and they all animate simultaneously. and yes, the second one, you got it, I tried to add margins or paddings to the sentences_block and it didnt work (I cannot fix the block's screen width can differ depending on resolution or device).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution for the multiple sentences would be to make each letter div a few lines high. You'll need to calculate maximum number of letter elements and keeping each sentence the same length, but using whitespace ou can get pretty much any sentence you want, keeping your actual code structure. Like this:

```
   var letters = document.location.hash ? document.location.hash.substr(1) : 'sentence';
   var line_2 = document.location.hash ? document.location.hash.substr(1) : 'another ';
   var line_3 = document.location.hash ? document.location.hash.substr(1) : ' again   ';

    $('<div>', {
        html: letters[i]+'<br>'+line_2[i]+'<br>'+line_3[i]
    })
```

For the width, I'm not sure I understand, but if you want the animation to stop where the options begin, the width of option can be calculated by adding the width of `#list` plus margin, plus padding. Or, more simply, width of animation can be equal to left offset of the list. Like this:

```
var width = $('#list').offset().left
```

see codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GJNMMP

Comment: Thats what I wanted thanks!! for the second question, if I fix the sentence_block width , it won't be correct with different page width.

 What I want can be said in a math equation... 

sentences_block width = page width(whatever it is) - #list width(including padding and margins). 
How can I make it like that? I hope I explained well this time

Comment: see edit, it's even simpler than that. You want your width will be equal to the left offset of the list.

Comment: any idea how to reverse direction? text would start at the right and finish at the left.

Comment: invert your array   for (i = letters.length-1; i >=0; i--) { and after setting posx modify it like this: posx = width -posx